# Twisted for Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, twisted

The Twisted [download page](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) shows that the current version for Macintosh is 8.2.0 for OS X 10.5

Are there known issues with this version of Twisted under 10.6, or is the Twisted web page just a bit out of date?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been closed as not programming related. Twisted is a python library for developing network applications. It seems as if the asker wants to know if the library will work for his setup.

Comment: Seriously, are people voting to close without even knowing what Twisted is?

Answer (score 3):

Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.x) comes with Twisted 8.2.0 installed with the system python. So, yes, it works. Apple's Calendar Server is a twisted app.

Answer (score 1):

The OS X installer for Twisted isn't quite the usual distutils-based installer and there's no automation in the Twisted release process for creating it.  This means availability of the installer for new versions of OS X or new versions of Twisted generally lag quite a bit.

However, the normal distutils-based installer (`setup.py install`) should accomplish the same thing.  The Twisted 9.0 test suite passes completely on OS X 10.6.  I suspect 8.2 also works, but I haven't seen the results of running the test suite.